# How can I replicate this functionality with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I'm switching a site that used to use **mysqli** to PDO. I have page that generates a `<li>` menu, split into two columns (ie two container divs).

In the mysqli version, I have the following code - `$num` is the number of rows returned by my query, `$recsToOutput` is half that number:

```
<div class="6u">
    <ul>
    <?php //Loop through first half of table and output name and link...
        for($i=1;$i <= $recsToOutput; $i++){ // for the first record to the half the number of rows...
        echo '<li><a href="#">';
        echo '<h3>'.$row['menu_item'].'</h3>';
        echo '</a></li>';
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
    ?>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="6u">
    <ul>
      <?php //.. loop through remaining entries and output
       for($i=$recsToOutput; $i < $num; $i++){ // for half the number of rows to the full number of rows...
       echo '<li><a href="#">';
       echo '<h3>'.$row['menu_item'].'</h3>';
       echo '</a></li>';
       $row=mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      }
      ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here, the `mysqli_fetch_array` calls moved the array pointer of `$row` on one in order to grab the next menu item. However, I obviously can't use that with PDO: how can I replicate the functionality (or do it better?)

Comment: It's not very "obvious" why you can't do the same with PDO.

Comment: Note that mysqli supports an OO implementation

Comment: It's not obvious to _me_, hence why I'm asking...

Comment: @Strawberry I can't use mysqli properly because my host doesn't support mysqlnd.

Comment: `$num = $sth->rowCount();`

Comment: Oh, I can just do a PDO fetch like I did in the first place. Idiot.